# Etymology of Greek Enualios

Tags: etymology, historical-linguistics, indo-european, greek, names

Enualios or Enyalius (Ἐνυάλιος) is, in Homer and other Greek authors, either an epithet of the war god Ares or else the name of a separate god, the son of Ares and brother or partner of Enyo (whose name seems to come from his). The name appears as early as Mycenaean, where it seems to refer to a separate god. What is the source of his name?

Chantraine says "no etymology, probably pre-Greek", but the name looks like a well-formed Greek prepositional compound: *en-ualios* would be "the one in the *hualos*". This word ὕαλος has several meanings: it later comes to mean "glass", but earlier on seems to have referred to some kind of crystalline stone, possibly alabaster, but also possibly to amber; and Hesychius gives an additional gloss equating it with βόρβορος "mire, mud, filth". None of these gives a clear meaning for the name, though: "the one in the crystal/stone/amber/mire" are not particularly obvious names for a war god.

Are there any good theories out there about the etymology of this name?

Comment: take a look at http://diachronica.pagesperso-orange.fr/TMCJ_them_02_Fournet_Enualios.pdf

Comment: @AlexB. Very speculative but still interesting, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should also consider the PIE preposition

***e̯neu*** without

which could be contracted to ***e̯nu-*** if used as a prefix.

and then in PIE we have

***a̯elios*** other

- So ***e̯nua̯elios*** looks like somebody without others (loner?).

And this can be supported by the tradition:

> (...) one tradition derived it from a Thracian Enyalius, who received
>   into his house those only who conquered him in single combat, and for
>   the same reason refused to receive Ares, but the latter slew him.
>   (Eustath. ad Hom. p. 673.)

*This text is from: A dictionary of Greek and Roman biography and mythology, 1873 (ed. William Smith).*

http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0104:entry=enyalius-bio-1

So here is the account by Eustathius (although it seems he in turn refers to Arianos):

[image]

While exact sound changes for Thracian are unknown, [the sound changes from PIE to Dacian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dacian_language#Sound_changes_from_Proto-Indo-European), a closely related language, often considered a dialect of Thracian or vise versa, and spoken in Thrace as well, bring exactly this form. The known differences between Thracian and Dacian do not affect this. As such, PIE ***e̯nua̯elios*** would give ***enualios*** in both Thracian and Dacian.

Comment: Αre you thinking of Greek ἄνευ? How do you get from /a/ to /e/?

Comment: @fdb well I do not know how to get from PIE h1 to Greek ἄ. In PIE it was h1. Note that the name is probably not of Greek origin, but Thracian, which is another IE language, so Greek laws not necessarily apply. For the PIE look here for instance: http://www.phil.muni.cz/linguistica/art/blazek/bla-001.pdf

Comment: "Greek laws do not apply" means you have no explanation. Do you know any Thracian sound laws?

Comment: @fdb well applying the generic late-PIE laws on the laryngeals (e̯ -> e, a̯e->a) we already reach the exact correspondence.

Comment: And from ἄλλος to –αλιος?

Comment: @fdb also in Greek we have the same reflex: ενεοζ "dumb" (without-mouth),  ενεοφρωζ "senseless". Regarding your last comment, what do u mean? In PIE - a̯elios meant "other".

Comment: Yes, but *lio becomes llo in Greek.

Comment: @fdb If the origin is Thracian, applying Greek rules is senseless, I applied only the common late-PIE rules because it is known that Thracian was an IE language. And given it was that ancient language, it could not be too far from late PIE. It is reasonable to assume that Thracian retained -lio- as -lio- rather than following Greek pattern towards -llo-

Comment: I cannot discuss a language for which there is virtually no evidence.

Comment: @fdb It could be any conservative enough IE language (the region had a lot of them), even in Greek the compound would look like ἄνευἄλλος or ενευἄλλος, quite close. For instance, the Dacian sound changes allow exactly for this development, with Dacian often considered a dialect of Thracian (or vise versa): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dacian_language#Sound_changes_from_Proto-Indo-European and no known differences between Dacian and Thracian make this etymology impossible.

Comment: @fdb anyway, I am quite sure the -ios suffix corresponds to the same suffix of PIE. It is difficult to doubt it.